# How can I replace the text of an HTML tag

Tags: jquery, html, text, tags, innerhtml

I don't know how to call it but let me call it semi-inner text.

Example

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    This is the semi-inner text
    <div id='other'></div>
    This is the semi-inner text
<div>
```

I want to remove/replace those `This is the semi-inner text` using jquery.

How can I do that?

Comment: wrap it inside `<span class="semiTxt"></span>` and replace the text inside it using JS

Comment: You should wrap it with span, div, p or something. It's not a valid html page if some text is not wrapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about child nodes...

```
$('#myDiv').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function() {
    this.data = this.data.replace(/This is the semi-inner text/g, 'swapped');
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPE9Y/).

If you want to check all descendant nodes, make the function recurse when it detects an element node (`this.nodeType == 1`).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myDiv')
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    })
    .each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use contents() and filter out all nodeType that is equal to 3 and remove them:

```
$('#myDiv').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to replace the content

```
$("#other").html("your code");
```

and user wrap your code in span tag with id

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to place it in a span with an id like so:

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    <span id="myInnerText">This is the semi-inner text</span>
    <div id='other'></div>
    This is the semi-inner text
<div>
```

Then replace it like this:

```
$("#myInnerText").text("replacement text");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do it like this:

```
target_div = $("#myDiv")
  reg_exp  = /This is the semi-inner text/g;
  new_text = "some other text"

  target_div.html(
    target_div.html()
      .replace(
        new RegExp(reg_exp),
        new_text)
        );
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/96fH2/)